# How to insert an icon in css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, pseudo-element, glyphicons

I tried to insert an icon in css with the code below :

```
content: "\f103";
```

But it does not work.

[image]

If I add the following line, it does not work :

```
font-family: FontAwesome;
```

[image]

I would like to do as in the following example, add a product to the cart and go to the order :

https://demo.commercekickstart.com

[image]

Comment: What version of font awesome are you using (look like v5 to me)? Please [edit] the post and include  the missing details and the actual code as a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You should use fontAwesome in your css file add this :

```
font-family: FontAwesome;
```

Comment: If you are using fontAwesome v5 so you should use it like this :


  `.calendar::before {
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
      font-weight: 400; 
      content: "\f133";
  }`

and for the bold icons you should add this : `font-weight: 900;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's whats going on:

You're trying to insert the unicode character [U+F103](https://utf8-icons.com/utf-8-character-61699) into your page. This character is part of the Private Use Area Unicode subset. This is a character range that unicode has promised not to map any characters to, so that icon fonts and applications can use these values.

Most icons you see will have a unicode value, such as `content: "\f103";` and an icon font, such as FontAwesome.

If you want to include an icon font, you also need to import the font in your website.
In the case of FontAwesome, you can follow their "[How To Use](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css)" by adding `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">` to the head of your html documents.

Once you do that, you can find the icon you want, such as this [info circle](https://fontawesome.com/icons/info-circle?style=solid) and click one of the copy options at the top.

If you copy their html, put it on your page like `<i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>`. `.fas` sets the font family for you, and `.fa-info-circle` sets the appropriate unicode symbol.

Comment: They might be using the SVG & JS method and if that is the case, the OP also need to add the `data-search-pseudo-elements` attribute to the script tag of font awesome

Comment: @Alexander Rice I am using the SVG version for my site. Is there the possibility of using Glyphicons instead?

Comment: @838dbde324 As I wrote in my comment to your question - Please edit your post and include the actual code - Show us how you load Font Awesome (This part is **important**), include the HTML structure with the element you're trying to handle + the related CSS (including the `font-weight` and `font-family`

Comment: @AlonEitan I use Drupal 8 and make awesome is directly added to my sub theme `fonts/fontawesome/js/all.min.js: {}` The html structure and the css is in the screenshot